# Iterating a function

Tags: functions, function-construction, conditional, iterators

I have a piecewise map of the form

$M\left ( x \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2x & x<0.5 \\ 
 2-2x& x>0.5
\end{matrix}\right.$

The domain is the closed interval from 0 to 1.

I would like to iterated this map such that at some x value, f(x)=x. The result is then printed and the iteration stops.

What is a good way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Solve`? I.e. ``f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 0.5}, {2 - 2 x, x >= 0.5}}]; Solve[ f[x] == x, x]``

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 0.5}, {2 - 2 x, x >= 0.5}}, {x, 0, 1}];
fc[n_] := NestWhileList[f, n, # != f[#] &]
```

For n = 0.4, `fc[0.4]` returns

> {0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, \
>   0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, \
>   0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.799999, 0.400002, 0.800003, \
>   0.399994, 0.799988, 0.400024, 0.800049, 0.399902, 0.799805, 0.400391, \
>   0.800781, 0.398438, 0.796875, 0.40625, 0.8125, 0.375, 0.75, 0.5, 1., \
>   0.}

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the result or the process of iterations? If the first, then:

```
f = Piecewise[{{2 x, x < 0.5}, {2 - 2 x, x >= 0.5}}, {x, 0, 1}];
FindInstance[f - x == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, x, 5]
{{x -> 0}, {x -> 2/3}}
```

Otherwise you need look how to use the `EvaluationMonitor` with `FindInstance`

Comment: By "process of iteration", do you mean the `Print` function? If, yes, I could do that. 
As to your proposed solution, would using Conditionals and Loops be more handy?
Edit: I think I see what you're asking. I can see that x=2/3 is a fixed point on a map. But what I want to achieve is to start with a value x, find the image of x under the function, put that image value back into the function and repeat until f(x)=x, at which point the loop breaks.

Comment: My solution directly gives you the points where f(x)=x with `$MachinePrecision`. There are two such points in the range [0,1] as you can see. Any hand-made iterative solutions need to play with x-step adjustment. 
I asked you about what exactly do you need namely to understand what is your goal - to realize the process of iterations or to find the stop-point.